How do I get color coded entries in the iPhone Calendar app?
I recently came across this image* of the iPhone Calendar app in Dark Mode, which got me trying to figure out how to get my Calendar to look like this, with each entry having a color-coded background.  All I can get is the thin color bar to the left of the entry.  Is this image from some "alternate universe" version of the Calendar app - possibly one that never made it to production?

* original image URL:
https://imgix.bustle.com/inverse/f7/48/9d/b3/85a5/4804/9ef7/3689b5796ee7/apple-calendar-app-in-dark-mode.png?w=438&h=869&fit=crop&crop=faces
(URL claims to be downloading a .png file, but the actual file has an .avif extension when saved. I had to convert it to get it to display here.)
page using this image:
https://www.inverse.com/article/56453-iphone-dark-mode-release

Those are just events from different calendars.  The user can assign different colours to their different calendars.  Tap the word "calendars" at the bottom of the screen

I've already done that, but as I said, the only difference I'm seeing is a thin bar at the left end of the entry - not the full block highlighting like in the image.

Not sure. My calendar looks exactly like the one in your screenshot. Your question is off topic for this site, however, as it is not about programming

I thought I had found the most relevant place to post this; apparently I got that wrong, and for that I apologize, but it might help those who come across this post in the future if you could suggest a more appropriate location for similar questions.

Try askDifferent

I just realized I was looking at a different screen than the one shown above; the color blocks only appear on the "single day" view (with a week of day numbers at the top), and I generally don't have enough events to make this efficient, so I use the "schedule" view instead (which just shows however much fits on the screen, whether it's half a day or a week and a half, and which one gets to by tapping the three lines icon at top to highlight it).
This means that my question is essentially unanswerable, except by TPTB at Apple, and in the form of "Why is this level of highlighting not available in all views?"
